# data.table assignment operator with lists in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table containing a `name` column, and I'm trying to extract a regular expression from this name. The most obvious way to do it in this case is with the `:=` operator, as I'm assigning this extracted string as the actual name of the data. In doing so, I find that this doesn't actually apply the function in the way that I would expect. I'm not sure if it's intentional, and I was wondering if there's a reason it does what it does or if it's a bug.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(name = c('foo123', 'bar234'))
```

Searching for the desired expression in a simple character vector behaves as expected:

```
name <- dt[1, name]
pattern <- '(.*?)\\d+'
regmatches(name, regexec(pattern, name))
[[1]]
[1] "foo123" "foo"
```

I can easily subset this to get what I want

```
regmatches(name, regexec(pattern, name))[[1]][2]
[1] "foo"
```

However, I run into issues when I try to apply this to the entire data.table:

```
dt[, name_final := regmatches(name, regexec(pattern, name))[[1]][2]]
dt
    name name_final
1: foo123        foo
2: bar234        foo
```

I don't know how data.table works internally, but I would guess that the function was applied to the entire `name` column first, and then the result is coerced into a vector somehow and then assigned to the new `name_final` column. However, the behavior I would expect here would be on a row-by-row basis. I can emulate this behavior by adding a dummy `id` column;

```
dt[, id := seq_along(name)]
dt[, name_final := regmatches(name, regexec(pattern, name))[[1]][2], by = list(id)]
dt
    name name_final id
1: foo123        foo  1
2: bar234        bar  2
```

Is there a reason that this isn't the default behavior? If so, I would guess that it had to do with columns being atomic to the data.table rather than the rows, but I'd like to understand what's going on there.

Comment: If it was actually this simple then yes, I could. The actual expression I'm searching for is a more complicated, but I thought a simple example would illustrate the issue a bit better.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to extract a capture group that matches a more complex regular expression than simply 'get all characters until numbers'. The capture group makes regexec necessary (I think), and the regular expression itself makes it harder to just use gsub.

Comment: @RichardScriven what you said about the rows makes sense though, I wasn't sure whether or not data.table passes the entire column as an argument to the function or actually operates row-by-row when using the `:=` operator. The answer provided seems to answer that

Comment: I was referring to your claim that the function was not operating on a row by row basis. The `name <- dt[1, name]` part was incorrect, but also not relevant since that's not what I operate on after that in the example anyway

Comment: @RichardScriven regarding the `regexec` return value, however, this is straight from the documentation: "regexec returns a list of the same length as text"

Comment: My fault.  I was thinking of `regexpr`. At any rate, I still think a capture group with `gsub` would be a better choice for you here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much nothing in R runs on a row-by-row basis. It's always better to work with columns of data at a time so you can pretty much assume that the entire column vector of values will be passed in as a parameter to your function. Here's a way to extract the second element for each item in the regmatches list

```
dt[, name_final := sapply(regmatches(name, regexec(pattern, name)), `[`, 2)]
```

Functions like `sapply()` or `Vectorize()` can "fake" a per-row type call for functions that aren't meant to be run on a vector/list of data at a time.

Comment: So this works because it's basically acting on each element of the resulting list and just getting the second element, converting the result into a vector that can be easily bound to the table as a new column?

Comment: Right. The idea is if you pass in a vector to a function, you should get a vector out of the same length. So we assume the `name` values will be passed in as a vector, and just want to make sure our expression returns a vector (one result for each element). This is very much by design and nearly all base functions in are are "vectorized" to accommodate this behavior. It's what makes R so nice to work with in the first place.